couchbase nodejs sdk crashes on init
So we’re using couchbase nodejs sdk 4.2.11.
when the service runs up we get this issue:

terminate called after throwing an instance of
‘tao::pegtl::parse_error’ what(): tao::json::events::from_string:1:7:
invalid escaped unicode code point

saw similar threads. but no concrete answer relevant to nodejs sdk - or anything relatable.
any ideas?
a more understandable error?

Would you mind posting the code that leads up to this error? Also, which version of Couchbase Server (or Capella) are you using?

I find a couchbase jira ticket with that error that is “fixed”. Please use version 4.3.1
